# Cannot resolve method 'installSplashScreen' in 'SplashScreen'

Tags: android-12

I'm trying to migrate my existing custom Splash screen implementation to Android 12. I have implemented it exact same way as mentioned in the provided link : [as mentioned in the provided link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/splash-screen-migration)

When I write following statement in my SplashActivity, it shows error:

**SplashActivity.java**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
 }
```

the error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'installSplashScreen' in 'SplashScreen'
```

for

```
SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
```

I have added the following dependency:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

Answer (score 25):

When I imported the **SplashScreen**, the default import was:

```
import android.window.SplashScreen;
```

And this was the only import available and there was no option to choose from.

After [reading the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen), the package name seems to be the following:

```
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
```

I had to manually change the above import statement. I don't know why I didn't get to choose between the two.

Even after changing the import, SplashScreen was still red(showing error) during compile-time, but I could able to build and run the project without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Writing  `installSplashScreen()` is enough in koltin class,

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        installSplashScreen()
}
```