# Cannot Find Symbol SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);

Tags: java, android, splash-screen

Using [developer.android migration guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate) for splash screens in android 12. My build.grade has

```
android {
   compileSdkVersion 31
   ...
}
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha01'
}
```

Manifest and theme also set up. The issue I am having is with

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         // Handle the splash screen transition.
         SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
         setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
}
```

I am getting error: cannot find symbol SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this); with the .installSplashScreen part of code in red in Android Studio.

I have seen [this stack post with some suggestions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68712878/cannot-resolve-method-installsplashscreen-in-splashscreen) I have tried both

```
import android.window.SplashScreen;
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
```

But still getting cannot find symbol.

Comment: I too tried and got the very same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is correct usage - but maybe this?

```
androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case if use this version:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.1.0-alpha01'
```

import does not work!
but if use older version:

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha01'
```

it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue basically I was importing  this

```
import android.window.SplashScreen;
```

instead of  this

```
 import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

What compiled is:
a)

```
import androidx.core.splashscreen.SplashScreen;
```

b)

`SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);`

I had to manually expand installSplashScreen() to
the line above.

Note that this -does- compile now. But i still get a white screen, so maybe it does not finally work. While i write this i still use a png as icon, while the spec asks for an animated svg. This could also be the reason i see a white screen instead of a real splash screen.